# How to remove tooltip window (on mouse over) from the google visualization core chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, google-code

I want to remove the default tooltip window which occur when mouse-over event fire on a point of a line chart/area chart(new) from the core chart library. Also I want to know how to remove event from the visualization core chart of the google.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set trigger to 'none

```
chart.draw(data, {trigger:'none'});
```